# Apache FilesNotMatch regex?

Tags: regex, apache, httpd.conf

I'm looking for something like FilesNotMatch (like filesmatch, but is triggered when the regex returns false), how can I do something like this? I'm doing this right now:

```
<FilesMatch "/(log22.swf|packer.swf|sos.swf|e.swf|newBubbleSystem.swf|aeVisual.swf)$">
#Stuff here
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FilesNotMatch is not necessary. Just

```
<FilesMatch "/!(log22.swf|packer.swf|sos.swf|e.swf|newBubbleSystem.swf|aeVisual.swf)$">
#Stuff here
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: This answer was 8 years ago, but this chosen answer doesn't work for me.